# DataGridView insert in DB on new row

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I have the following code to populate a DataGridView:

```
private void LoadCashOut_raRecSheetChecks(int recID)
  {
   SqlDataAdapter SqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

   SqlCommand SqlCommand_Select = new SqlCommand("raRecSheetChecks_Get", SqlConn);
   SqlCommand_Select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   SqlCommand_Select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recID", recID));

   SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = SqlCommand_Select;

   DataSet DS_recSheetChecks = new DataSet();

   SqlAdapter.Fill(DS_recSheetChecks);

   // DataGridView GV_ChecksRolledCoins
   GV_ChecksRolledCoins.DataSource = DS_recSheetChecks.Tables[0]; 
  }
```

What I would like to do is insert into the same DB whenever a user completes a new row.

How do I tell the DataGridView to fire an event to insert when a new row has been created?

Side question: I need to do the same thing except update instead of insert for rows that have been modified.

I'd like to do this without a "Save" button. Simply, I want the data to be inserted or updated as soon as the user leaves the row.

Comment: Couldn't you wire-up an [EventListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener) to handle this for you?  This class is designed _specifically_ for what you are trying to accomplish.  (Provided I didn't misunderstand your question.)

Comment: @Brandon you mean write DataGridView event handler? Which event?

Comment: I was thinking that since you want to insert the new row once it has been created, wire the listener to check when the end-user leaves the new row they have created, then have your code insert it.

Comment: @Brandon That's what I was thinking except that the RowLeave event fires when existing rows are loaded. Meaning it would fire on loading of the data. I also tried RowsAdded and UserAddedRow but those fire as soon as the row is created BEFORE the user enters any data. I can't seem to find an event that only fires after a new row is created. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you look into using the [DataGridView.RowValidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx) event, yet?  Edit:  There is also a [Control.Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated(v=vs.110).aspx) event as well.

Comment: Yup. No go. It also fires on load for every row.